# Is it possible to specify directory wildcards in Directory.GetFiles?

Tags: .net, file, directory

I have a directory structure to sift through and I need to be able to specify the top-level folder, a typical example would be:

```
c:\folder1\1\targetfolder
c:\folder1\2\targetfolder
c:\folder1\3\targetfolder
c:\folder1\4\targetfolder
```

I want to obtain each file in the folder called *targetfolder*, specifying this seems to fail:

```
Directory.GetFiles("c:\folder1\*\targetfolder");
```

Is there a quick and easy way of achieving this?

Comment: Try ** instead, this what they use in MSBuild.

Comment: Already tried **, same exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with this and works, but you could get false positives if there are file or folders inside your root path with the same pattern

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\folder1", "*.*", 
        SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(n => n.Contains("\\targetfolder\\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and doesn't have side effects if you have files named `targetfolder` or similar.

```
Directory.GetDirectories(
    @"c:\folder1\",
    @"targetfolder",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .SelectMany(dir => Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
```

This will get you the files that exist only within fodlers named `targetfolder` within the folder `c:\folder1\`